# Why ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver makes redirect instead of simple response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've written a few extensions of ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver, it intercepts all exceptions that it should, but instead of returning only error message and HTTP status code it makes really weird redirect by its own URL built upon users requested URL. For instance:

```
user's url -> .../myModule/api/myEntity/123 (it's an id)
resolver's redirect url -> .../myModule/api/myEntity/myEntity/123
```

Server doesn't have such resource and obviously it will respond with 404.

The question is: why it makes redirect and how to configure it to return only a message and status code?

My resolver:

```
public class BusinessLayerExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView wrappedResponse = new ModelAndView();
        wrappedResponse.addObject("errorMessage", ex.getMessage());
        wrappedResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return wrappedResponse;
    }
}
```

I guess the usage of `ModelAndView` assumes redirection. At least that's a method description that I found in DispatcherServlet.

```
...
     * @return a corresponding ModelAndView to forward to
     * @throws Exception if no error ModelAndView found
     */
    protected ModelAndView processHandlerException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
...
```

If so, how to make it return just error message and HTTP status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return just error message and HTTP status code by creating a custom `View`.

```
public class YourCustomView implements View {

    private final String errorMessage;

    public YourCustomView(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter()) {
            pw.write(errorMessage);
        }
    }

}
```

You need to put the custom `View` object into `ModelAndView` object in `HandlerExceptionResolver#resolveException`.

```
public class BusinessLayerExceptionHandler implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView wrappedResponse = new ModelAndView();
        wrappedResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        wrappedResponse.setView(new YourCustomView(ex.getMessage()));
        return wrappedResponse;
    }
}
```

> why it makes redirect

It seems that Spring recognize the view name as a `defaultViewName` and forwards to it (by calling `RequestDispatcher#forward`).
In `DispatcherServlet#processHandlerException`, a `defaultViewName` is set to the view name of a `ModelAndView` returned by `resolveException` when it doesn't have `View` object. A `defaultViewName` is got from `DispatcherServlet#getDefaultViewName` that translates a HTTP request into a view name.

**Another Solution**

I think you may be able to use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` instead. It also can handle an exception thrown from a controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class YourControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleBusinessLayerException(
            Exception exception) {
        Map<String, String> body = Map.of("errorMessage", exception.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(body);
    }

}
```

**See Also**

[Spring Web MVC document about HandlerExceptionResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers)
[Spring Web MVC document about ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice)